# Youtube Audio and Video go out of sync in Chrome and some of my other videos

Tags: google-chrome, audio, video, sync

Hi i had a question since i cant seem to figure out whats wrong YouTube also some of the videos on my computer the sound will be out of sync withe the video. Its like a 1 second laps in the video. i seems to be happening on other sites to like Netflix.

Comment: So, it's happening in streaming but not with local files?